# Getting KeyError when trying to find out the global average rating of users

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a movie recommendation system and want to print the average of all the user ratings from my train sample data.

Code:

```
globalAvgUsers = getAverageRatings(train_sample_sparse, True)
print("Average user rating for user 16879 is {}".format(globalAvgMovies[16879]))
```

This code renders an error in the .format function showing:

```
print("Average user rating for user 16879 is {}".format(globalAvgMovies[16879]))

KeyError: 16879
```

Please tell me where and why I need to make the changes.

Comment: try `globalAvgMovies[[16879]]`

Comment: So what is `globalAvgUsers` and why do you think you need to index it with `16879`?

Comment: have u checked that dictionary globalAvgMovies has the key 16879?

Comment: You sure want to print an entry from `globalAvgMovies`? The print message suggests that you want to print an element from `globalAvgUsers` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `16879` does not exist in globalAvgMovies (assuming that `globalAvgUsers` returns a dictionary). To avoid this error, you could use:

`globalAvgMovies.get(16879, "Enter default value here")`

[python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Full Code:

```py
globalAvgUsers = getAverageRatings(train_sample_sparse, True)
print("Average user rating for user 16879 is {}".format(globalAvgMovies.get(16879,"Default Value")))
```

Comment: Notice that there are 2 different variables involved in OP's code (and yours): `globalAvgUsers` and `globalAvgMovies`.